# Issue with add global variable codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3

I've admin dashboard with header available in all pages.

in Admin Controller I add function:

```
`class Admin_controller extends Admin_Core_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        
        $data['notification_count'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_all_notifications_count();
        $data['notification'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_all_notifications();


        $this->load->view('admin/includes/_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/index');
        $this->load->view('admin/includes/_footer');
    }
}`
```

The problem is this working only for "home page (index)" dashboard. When I open anyother page then I get issue undefinied variable.

How can I call this variables in global?

```
`
        $data['notification_count'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_all_notifications_count();
        $data['notification'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_all_notifications();`
```

update:

I've one file Core_Controller.php and this file contains:

```
class Admin_Core_Controller extends Core_Controller
```

{

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if (!is_admin()) {
        redirect(admin_url() . 'login');
        exit();
    }

    //set control panel lang
    $this->control_panel_lang = $this->selected_lang;
    if (!empty($this->session->userdata('mds_control_panel_lang'))) {
        $this->control_panel_lang = $this->session->userdata('mds_control_panel_lang');
        //language translations
        $this->language_translations = $this->get_translation_array($this->control_panel_lang->id);
    }

    //check long cron
    if (check_cron_time_long() == true) {
        //delete old sessions
        $this->settings_model->delete_old_sessions();
        //add last update
        $this->db->where('id', 1)->update('general_settings', ['last_cron_update_long' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
    }
}

protected function render($view, $data = NULL)
{
    $data['notification_count'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_all_notifications_count();
    $data['notification'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_all_notifications();

    $this->load->view('admin/includes/_header', $data);
    $this->load->view($view, $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/includes/_footer');
}

public function paginate($url, $total_rows)
{
    //initialize pagination
    $page = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->get('page'));
    $per_page = $this->input->get('show', true);
    $page = clean_number($page);
    if (empty($page) || $page <= 0) {
        $page = 0;
    }

    if ($page != 0) {
        $page = $page - 1;
    }

    if (empty($per_page)) {
        $per_page = 15;
    }
    $config['num_links'] = 4;
    $config['base_url'] = $url;
    $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
    $config['reuse_query_string'] = true;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    return array('per_page' => $per_page, 'offset' => $page * $per_page);
}
```

}

You see I add your code here and now in Admin_Controller I add:

```
class Admin_controller extends Admin_Core_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = trans("admin_panel");

        $data['order_count'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_all_orders_count();
        $data['product_count'] = $this->product_admin_model->get_products_count();
        $data['pending_product_count'] = $this->product_admin_model->get_pending_products_count();
        $data['blog_posts_count'] = $this->blog_model->get_all_posts_count();
        $data['members_count'] = $this->auth_model->get_users_count_by_role('member');
        $data['latest_orders'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_orders_limited(15);
        $data['latest_pending_products'] = $this->product_admin_model->get_latest_pending_products(15);
        $data['latest_products'] = $this->product_admin_model->get_latest_products(15);
        
        
        

        $data['latest_reviews'] = $this->review_model->get_latest_reviews(15);
        $data['latest_comments'] = $this->comment_model->get_latest_comments(15);
        $data['latest_members'] = $this->auth_model->get_latest_members(6);
        $data['latest_transactions'] = $this->transaction_model->get_transactions_limited(15);
        $data['latest_promoted_transactions'] = $this->transaction_model->get_promoted_transactions_limited(15);

        $this->load->view('admin/includes/_header', $data);
        $this->render('admin/index');
        $this->load->view('admin/includes/_footer');
        
    }
```

and after this dashboard now working and everytime is refreshed every sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a base controller with a `render` function, then have your controllers extend from this base controller and use this function to render their pages. The `render` function can then contain the variables that need to be available on all pages.

Since you already have an `Admin_Core_Controller` class, you might be able to add the `render` function there instead (not sure of your project structure). Something like this:

```
class Admin_Core_Controller // ...
{
    // ...

    protected function render($view, $data = NULL)
    {
        $data['notification_count'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_all_notifications_count();
        $data['notification'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_all_notifications();
    
        $this->load->view('admin/includes/_header', $data);
        $this->load->view($view, $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/includes/_footer');
    }
}
```

Then use it to render your page in `Admin_Controller`:

```
class Admin_controller extends Admin_Core_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->render('admin/index');
    }
}
```

---

**Edit** Your `Admin_Controller` class should look like this - I've removed the header and footer includes (those are already rendered by the `render` function) and passed the `$data` array to `render`:

```
class Admin_controller extends Admin_Core_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = trans("admin_panel");

        $data['order_count'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_all_orders_count();
        $data['product_count'] = $this->product_admin_model->get_products_count();
        $data['pending_product_count'] = $this->product_admin_model->get_pending_products_count();
        $data['blog_posts_count'] = $this->blog_model->get_all_posts_count();
        $data['members_count'] = $this->auth_model->get_users_count_by_role('member');
        $data['latest_orders'] = $this->order_admin_model->get_orders_limited(15);
        $data['latest_pending_products'] = $this->product_admin_model->get_latest_pending_products(15);
        $data['latest_products'] = $this->product_admin_model->get_latest_products(15);
        
        
        

        $data['latest_reviews'] = $this->review_model->get_latest_reviews(15);
        $data['latest_comments'] = $this->comment_model->get_latest_comments(15);
        $data['latest_members'] = $this->auth_model->get_latest_members(6);
        $data['latest_transactions'] = $this->transaction_model->get_transactions_limited(15);
        $data['latest_promoted_transactions'] = $this->transaction_model->get_promoted_transactions_limited(15);

        $this->render('admin/index', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please check my update

Comment: thanks for update. I changed code. Now this working but still only for main page index.  myweb.com/admin  when I open example: myweb.com/admin/orders then I get from header undefinied variable ; ( because this variable notifications count I have in header and dislay in all pages.

Comment: /admin working https://prnt.sc/8qG26ZsvAaUD     other pages https://prnt.sc/DSS2PT6aE59f

Comment: That's correct. Now you need to go through all of your other admin controller methods, and change the `$this->load->view(...)` lines to `$this->render(...)` just as you did with the `index` function.